# How to extract/create/recover a private .key file with ECPARAM from .pem or .csr file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, pem, csr

Had run below commands to generate a .csr and .key file under /opt/certs/ folder.

```
1) openssl ecparam -out name.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
2) openssl req -new -sha384 -key name.key -out name.csr -config name.cnf
3) openssl req -in name.csr -text
```

However, now the folder /opt/certs/ is deleted after reboot and the name.key file is lost. I have the name.csr file as backup and name.pem key file also generated/available.

Is there a way to recover or recreate/generate ".key" file again from the existing name.csr and/or name.pem files, without re-issuing or re-creating again certs ?  The output of the lost .key file had BEGIN/END EC PARAMETERS, followed by BEGIN/END EC PRIVATE KEY

Thanks!

Comment: The ".csr" does not contain private key. It contains public part of the key pair and other stuff. So, you can not recover private key by using it.
".pem" files can contain different kind of objects. If there is "BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY" in your "name.pem", then it might be the private key what you are looking for.

Comment: .pem file doesn't contain any Begin EC Private Key.

Comment: If you find a way to recover a private key from just the public key, you'll be destroying the usefulness of many, many cryptographic schemes on your way to winning a Nobel Prize in mathematics.

Comment: Hahaha, so, it's not possible then :)